# VSTO:Ambiguity between methods

Tags: ms-word, vsto

I found the answer [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/csharpgeneral/thread/90fa8541-316e-4fac-9885-7c28ef9653b1/). However, I can't find _Application nor _Document with reference to Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word. I did `using Word = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word;` then I tried to look up _Document and _Application but all I can find is Document and Application. I believe the Document interface inherited _Document and DocumentEvents2. Does anyone know how to solve this pesky warning? edit: this is for Office 2010 and I'm using the version 14 Interop.Word

Comment: What pesky warning? It's not mentioned in your question or is the warning actually "ambiguity between methods"? In general, though, you don't reference or make use of _Document, _Application or really _Anything in VSTO or IExtensibility. Use the plain old "Document", "Application" or whatever objects.

Comment: The pesky warning is in Visual Studio2010 where I want to close the document and called .Close() method. A squiggly line will appear and give the Ambiguity warning. I am using the plain old Document and Application but from the solution that I found. People seem to be able to use _Document and _Application to get rid of Ambiguity warning. edit: using Document and Application is causing the Ambiguity problem.

Comment: Can you display the exact lines of code that generate the "pesky warning"? I am trying to replicate this in Word but get nothing pesky so far.

Comment: You have acces to Document but not _Document ? If you using correcty interop.word, you may have _Document.

Answer (score 0):

Word is not my area, but in general this message appears when an interface (Word) implements two interfaces, each having a similarly called method. To avoid the warning, you need to cast specifically to the underlying interface you are interested in.
There is an illustration with Worksheet.Activate() (an equivalent problem in Excel) [here](http://www.clear-lines.com/blog/post/Warning-ambiguous-method-call-in-VSTO.aspx).

Comment: The problem is there is no Word._Document. The Document does implement two interfaces that have close method.